Oxide with a low decomposition temperature
For nosecone separation on a rocket we plan on using black powder charges. However, these charges are unreliable in the low oxygen environments present at high altitudes.
Despite promising results in a vacuum chamber, we are still uncertain of a how consistent the charges are. Is there a metal oxide (other than HgO) or similar compound that could decompose into oxygen gas at temperatures under 300°C?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_oxygen_generator might be of interest

Can you explain what you mean when speaking of "unreliable charges in low oxygen environment" ?

Black powder does not require external oxygen. There must be other factors, as temperature, air pressure, moisture condensation etc.

$\ce{NaCuO2}$ ?

The chemical oxygen generators is pretty much exactly what we were looking for. Black powder charges are pretty unreliable at high altitudes (ie they either won't go off or won't provide enough force to separate the nosecone) which we have assumed to be from the lack of oxygen however we will definitely test the other factors mentioned to ensure higher consistency.

This question is similar to: Oxygen production from thermal decomposition of metal oxides. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Or $\ce{2 KClO3 ->[MnO2][\pu{200-300 ^{\circ}C}] 2 KCl + 3 O2}$
($\pu{400 ^{\circ}C}$ without $\ce{MnO2}$)

Not fitting based on context of question but when used Hydroxylammonium nitrate (HAN)/polyvinylalcohol (PVA) propellant based catalyst, most of the metal oxides (e.g. $\ce{Al2O3,Fe2O3,V2O5}$) gets decomposed within the temperature range of 150 C-250 C. It is described in this paper: https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/27787991.pdf

Among binary oxides, silver oxide decomposes above 280°C. It is also conveniently prepared from aqueous solutions, because addition of alkali to a soluble silver salt gives the oxide rather than hydroxide precipitate.
